# How do i setup PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, installation

I am following https://www.drupal.org/node/1438206, but i got stuck at Point 2. i.e Add the bin directory of postgres, /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin to the PATH in your .bashrc file in your home directory. Remember to run ./.bashrc to update the path.

I installed postgreSQL using brew. Now i do not find /Library/PostgreSQL/*/bin path i.e I do not find PostgreSQL inside Library.
Also i do not find .bashrc file .

I have installed postgreSQL for sure.Please help me out.

Comment: The `.bashrc` should be in your HOME directory (run `cd ~` or just `cd`in Terminal). If there is no such file, you can create it. To find the original executable for `psql` and you are sure you installed it, look into `/usr/bin/local`to find a symlink to the original file.

Comment: Also note that PostgreSQL you're installing is fairly old. Please see my answer.

Comment: Please note that questions about installing a DBMS are off topic here as they're independent of Drupal

Comment: I am reposting my question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I highly, highly suggest not installing these things directly to the operating system. It will just be more problematic instead of using a contained, virtual environment.

Instead, I advise using virtual environments (Vagrant/Docker). I use [DrupalVM](http://www.drupalvm.com) for development. For PostgreSQL you can see [this thread](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/146) for info on how to get it up and going.

Here is a [Docker flavored VM](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/) with instructions on PostgreSQL support.

The linked drupal.org page you mentioned is four years old. I wouldn't follow it.

Comment: I have vagrant setup for other projects on my system. But i do not know how to setup new vagrant enviroment for this  project as well there is postgreSQL. Can you please provide me basic steps. I tried to understand links you have given, but i could barely understand and am misdirected.

Comment: Yes, But that project is NOT a fresh vanilla drupal instance. I have to use it with MAMP + postgrepSQL.

Comment: https://github.com/mradcliffe/drupal8.dev

Comment: Other than my repo, also, DrupalVM should be a "fresh vanilla instance" for definitions of "fresh vanilla instance" that mean put the code base in place. https://github.com/beetboxvm/beetbox goes one step further and provisions databases and the site. What do you mean by "fresh vanilla instance"?